# How to connect to users of same app via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm writing an App that allows its users to automatically exchange data with other nearby users over BlueTooth. Normally, the two users would have to manually pair with each other before this could happen.

I was wondering if there was a way to bypass this step and automatically discover and connect to nearby users of my app, perhaps using some kind of app id signature for security?

Thank you!

Comment: I found a promising solution in another article, using a newer Bluetooth format: `One of the SSP mechanism allows for pairing without any intervention from the user. This method is called "Just-works" association model, the createInsecureRfcommSocket() API uses this method.`

Answer (score 2):

I see from your comment that you have already discovered the solution to the 'connect' part of your question: the API's for creating an insecure connection without manual pairing.

But that still leaves discovery.  In order to create a connection you need the Bluetooth address (bd addr) of the target.  To do this, you will need to get one user's phone into discoverable mode, and then do a discovery on the other phone.  This can't be done silently - your app can invoke these modes, but this will cause the phone to prompt the user.  No so bad, but probably not as automatic as you want.

If the two phones are on the same network, they could exchange bd_addr over the network - eliminating the need for discovery.  Or this could happen with a server as an intermediary, but this is a lot more work if you don't already plan to have a server.

Comment: Yeah, using a Wifi network is an interesting idea, but the majority of the communications will be coming from direct bluetooth connections. I believe I read that you can set in your code how long the device remains discoverable for - so for example couldn't I set the device to be discoverable continuously, only requiring the user to allow this once? This is just an idea and I'm sure there are security considerations to look into, but I also plan to give an option to the user to select how long they are discoverable for. However, that may be a pain if the user has to authorize it every time.

Comment: @Argus9 While Bluetooth supports the idea of being continuously discoverable, and older phones used to work that way, I believe that Android only supports time limited discoverability.  They have to authorize every time they want to find a NEW partner to communicate with, but only once per partner.  The bd_addr doesn't change.

Comment: I believe there is a method to call to make the device discoverable,  and one of the arguments it takes is how long you want the discovery time to last. If you put 0,  it stays in discoverable mode indefinitely.

Comment: Oh,OK, that's good.  One concern though is that (if  I remember correctly) calling that API  causes the user to be prompted.  Depending on what that prompt looks like it could be cause the user some concern.

Comment: True, but I'm going to make sure the user is fully informed beforehand. Then they only need to authorize it once per launch.